# Is there a bad interaction, in numpy 1.7.1, between datetime64 and vectorize?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to convert a pandas DateTimeIndex to excel dates (the number of days since 12/30/1899)..  I tried to use numpy.vectorize on a function that takes datetime64s and returns an excel date.  I was surprised by how numpy vectorize behaves - on the first call, a test call to see the return type, vectorize passes in datetime64 as provided.  On subsequent calls, it passes in the internal storage type of the datetime64 - in my case a long.  Internally, _get_ufunc_and_otypes calls:

```
inputs = [asarray(_a).flat[0] for _a in args]
outputs = func(*inputs)
```

While _vectorize_call does the following:

```
inputs = [array(_a, copy=False, subok=True, dtype=object) 
                  for _a in args]            

outputs = ufunc(*inputs)
```

As it turns out, I could just as easily use the internal numpy array math to do it (x - day0)/1day.  But this behavior seems strange (type changing when a function is vectorized)

Here's my sample code:

```
import numpy

DATETIME64_ONE_DAY   = numpy.timedelta64(1,'D')
DATETIME64_DATE_ZERO = numpy.datetime64('1899-12-30T00:00:00.000000000')

def excelDateToDatetime64(x):
   return DATETIME64_DATE_ZERO + numpy.timedelta64(int(x),'D')

def datetime64ToExcelDate(x):
   print type(x)
   return (x - DATETIME64_DATE_ZERO) / DATETIME64_ONE_DAY

excelDateToDatetime64_Array = numpy.vectorize(excelDateToDatetime64)
datetime64ToExcelDate_Array = numpy.vectorize(datetime64ToExcelDate)

excelDates = numpy.array([ 41407.0, 41408.0, 41409.0, 41410.0, 41411.0, 41414.0 ])
datetimes  = excelDateToDatetime64_Array(excelDates)
excelDates2 = datetime64ToExcelDate(datetimes)


print excelDates2  # Works fine

# TypeError: ufunc subtract cannot use operands with types dtype('int64') and dtype('<M8[ns]')
# You can see from the print that the type coming in is inconsistent
excelDates2 = datetime64ToExcelDate_Array(datetimes)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datetimes and timedeltas need to be handled using the underlying data (which you just do `arr.view('i8')` to get, these are `np.int64`)

Define your constants in terms of their underlying values

```
In [94]: DATETIME_DATE_ZERO_VIEW = DATETIME64_DATE_ZERO.view('i8')

In [95]: DATETIME_DATE_ZERO_VIEW
Out[95]: -2209161600000000000

In [96]: DATETIME64_ONE_DAY_VALUE = DATETIME64_ONE_DAY.astype('m8[ns]').item()

In [97]: DATETIME64_ONE_DAY_VALUE
Out[97]: 86400000000000L

In [106]: def vect(x):
   .....:     return (x-DATETIME_DATE_ZERO_VIEW)/DATETIME64_ONE_DAY_VALUE
   .....: 

In [107]: f = np.vectorize(vect)
```

Pass in a view of the underlying np.int64

```
In [109]: f(datetimes.view('i8'))
Out[109]: array([41407, 41408, 41409, 41410, 41411, 41414])
```

Pandas way

```
In [98]: Series(datetimes).apply(lambda x: (x.value-DATETIME_DATE_ZERO_VIEW)/DATETIME64_ONE_DAY_VALUE)
Out[98]: 
0    41407
1    41408
2    41409
3    41410
4    41411
5    41414
dtype: int64
```

Comment: That works - thanks very much.  The behavior the way I wrote it still seems odd to me (notably that the first call was passed a datetime64 and subsequent calls got the underlying np.int64)